Translated meshes appear tilted towards camera
I'm using Vulkan APIs to render meshes with the standard projection-view-model matrix approach. However, when translating objects, they appear tilted and distorted, always facing the camera. I don't think this is normal, because the deformation can get pretty bad and unnatural. (Also it’s just a translation, so the objects shouldn’t rotate at all).


I obtained the current results by hardcoding the matrices directly in my vertex shader as shown below:
void main() 
{   
    Vertex v = PushConstants.vertexBuffer.vertices[gl_VertexIndex];
    vec4 position = vec4(v.position, 1.0f);

    // Projection matrix
    mat4 proj = mat4(
        1.363963, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
        0.000000, 2.414213, 0.000000, 0.000000,
        0.000000, 0.000000, -1.000200, -1.000000,
        0.000000, 0.000000, -0.200020, 0.000000
    );

    // Translation matrix (used to position the camera)
    mat4 translation = mat4(
        1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
        0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
        0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000,
        0.000000, 0.000000, 10.000000, 1.000000
    );

    // Model matrix (scaling and positioning the object)
    mat4 model = mat4(
        0.100000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
        0.000000, 0.100000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
        0.000000, 0.000000, 0.100000, 0.000000,
        -6.000000, -1.500000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    );

    // View matrix (inverse of the translation matrix)
    mat4 view = inverse(translation);
    
    gl_Position = proj * view * model * position;
}

What I'm missing?
